# Dojo Toolkit JSONP on Youtube

Tags: dojo, youtube, jsonp

How can I  send JSONP request on Youtube video? I trying to get the video JSON info file using this code:

```
define ["dojo/request/script", "dojo/domReady!"], (script) ->
      script.get("//gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/NKE-RXR_XIs", {
        jsonp:"callback",
        query: {
          v: "2",
          alt: "json"
        }
      }).then (response) ->
        console.info response
```

But I getting error 400 (Bad Request). In Chrome console I can see full error:

```
GET http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/NKE-RXR_XIs?v=2&alt=json/[?&]callback=/dojo_request_script_callbacks.dojo_request_script0 400 (Bad Request)
```

Where cen by problem please?

Answer (score 0):

The good news, I don't think you are doing anything wrong. I have a similar problem using the Dojo toolkit v.1.8.3 to make JSON-P calls.

The bad news, I just tracked it down to a bug in: `dojo/request/script.js`

Dojo is making a bad request because a `RegExp` object is being appended to the URL query string instead of the callback parameter. You can see it in your error message as: `/[?&]callback=/`. 
That bit should just be: `&callback=`

Looks like they may get it fixed in v.1.8.4

http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/16408